# data corruption while converting from char * to stringstream and then back to char*

Tags: c++, buffer, x11, stringstream

So, i was trying my hands on XImage, created my first screen capture program and it worked fine. Now i wanted to send this XImage to another machine via thrift and save it there, but as there was some data reading problem from the client side, therefore i shifted the entire server side code to client side(for testing purpose. I will eventually move it back to server side)

Code :

```
transport->open();
Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
  XWindowAttributes gwa;
  XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, &gwa);

  int width = gwa.width;
  int height = gwa.height;
  XImage *image = XGetImage(display,root, 0,0 , width,height,AllPlanes, ZPixmap);

  char *data    = image->data;
  int imgwidth  = image->width;
  int imgheight = image->height;
  int depth     = image->depth;
  int offset    = 0;
  int xpad = 32; //may be 8 or 16 or 32
  int format = ZPixmap;
  int bytes_per_line = image->bytes_per_line;


  sendImage image_send;

  ostringstream s;
  //s<<image->data;
  s.write(image->data,(width)*(height));
  image_send.width  = imgwidth;
  image_send.height = imgheight;
  image_send.depth  = depth;
  image_send.offset = 2000;
  image_send.data   = s.str();
  image_send.xpad   = xpad;
  image_send.format = format;
  image_send.bytes_per_line = bytes_per_line;

 //server side code 
     int width1  = image_send.width;
     int height1 = image_send.height;
     int depth1  = image_send.depth;
     int offset1 = image_send.offset;
     char* tmp = new char[image_send.data.length() + 1];
     strcpy(tmp,image_send.data.c_str());
     char *data1 = tmp;
     int xpad1  = image_send.xpad;
     int format1 = image_send.format;
     int bytes_per_line1 = image_send.bytes_per_line;

     //Initialising X Operations
     //Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
     //Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
     //XWindowAttributes gwa;
    //XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, &gwa);

   int serverwidth = gwa.width;
   int serverheight = gwa.height;
   XImage *image1 = XCreateImage(display,DefaultVisual(display,DefaultScreen(display)),depth1, format1,offset1,data1,width1,height1,xpad1, bytes_per_line1);



   unsigned char *array = new unsigned char[width * height * 3];

   unsigned long red_mask = image1->red_mask;
   unsigned long green_mask = image1->green_mask;
   unsigned long blue_mask = image1->blue_mask;

   CImg<unsigned char> pic(array,width,height,1,3);

   for (int x = 0; x < width1; x++)
      for (int y = 0; y < height1 ; y++)
      {
         unsigned long pixel = XGetPixel(image1,x,y);

     unsigned char blue = pixel & blue_mask;
     unsigned char green = (pixel & green_mask) >> 8;
     unsigned char red = (pixel & red_mask) >> 16;



     array[(x + width1 * y) * 3] = red;
     array[(x + width1* y) * 3+1] = green;
     array[(x + width1 * y) * 3+2] = blue;

     pic(x,y,0,0) = red;
     pic(x,y,0,1) = green;
     pic(x,y,0,2) = blue;
  }



   pic.save_png("blah1.png");
```

As you can see i took the data part from the image pointer, wrote it into stream and then assigned that value to thrift object(image_send)

For the server side. i stored it into data1 using c_str() and then used XCreateImage using data1

This is the output that i get if i pass data1 as the source in XCreateImage

[image]

and this is the output i get if i use data(client side variable from original XImage)

[image]

As we can see there is a lot of blank space in the first image. On further inspection, i found that data1 contains a lot of null in the start where as data don't

So, i believe data gets corrupted while conversion from char * to string stream and then back to char *.

What suggestion would you give to correct this?
Update :

So, i was trying various things and it finally worked. The issue turns out to be buffer allocation and use of strcpy (i guess) which i changed to memcpy

```
int main() {

Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
XWindowAttributes gwa;
XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, &gwa);

int width = gwa.width;
int height = gwa.height;
XImage *image = XGetImage(display,root, 0,0 , width,height,AllPlanes, ZPixmap);

char *data    = image->data;
int imgwidth  = image->width;
int imgheight = image->height;
int depth     = image->depth;
int offset    = 0;
int xpad = 32; //may be 8 or 16 or 32
int format = ZPixmap;
int bytes_per_line = image->bytes_per_line;


//sendImage image_send;

ostringstream s;
//s<<image->data;
s.write(data,(width)*(height) * 4);

string stemp = s.str(); 
//server side code 
int width1  = width;
int height1 = height;
int depth1  = depth;
int offset1 = offset;
char* tmp = new char[stemp.length()];
//strcpy(tmp,stemp.c_str());
memcpy(tmp,stemp.data(),stemp.length());
char *data1 = tmp;
int xpad1  = 32;
int format1 = ZPixmap;
int bytes_per_line1 = bytes_per_line;

int serverwidth = gwa.width;
int serverheight = gwa.height;
XImage *image1 = XCreateImage(display,DefaultVisual(display,DefaultScreen(display)),depth1, format1,offset1,data1,serverwidth,serverheight,xpad1, bytes_per_line1);

unsigned char *array = new unsigned char[width * height];

unsigned long red_mask = image1->red_mask;
unsigned long green_mask = image1->green_mask;
unsigned long blue_mask = image1->blue_mask;

CImg<unsigned char> pic(array,width,height,1,3);

for (int x = 0; x < width1; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height1 ; y++)
    {
        unsigned long pixel = XGetPixel(image1,x,y);
        unsigned char blue = pixel & blue_mask;
        unsigned char green = (pixel & green_mask) >> 8;
        unsigned char red = (pixel & red_mask) >> 16;

        pic(x,y,0,0) = red;
        pic(x,y,0,1) = green;
        pic(x,y,0,2) = blue;
    }
}

pic.save_png("blah.png");

return 0;
}
```

However there are couple of things that i don't understand

1) when i am writing the data to stream why do i have to make the size of buffer as (width * height * 4). Anything less will crop the image proportionally. If i understand correctly, shouldn't be buffer size just equal to  width*height of the screen or is it structured more like array of Red,green,blue and depth?

2) My buffer size is about 4MB, however the image size is about 150K, is it due to encoding

3)Will Allocating and deallocating this much buffer size continuously, hamper performance?

**Edit : For future purpose**

The answer of first question is: we can get the same result using (bytes_per_line*height) which co-incidentally gave the same result as width*height*4

Answer (score 1):

Image data is binary, you cannot manipulate it as if it were a C string. The first zero byte will ruin the party.

Use `std::string::data()` and/or `memcpy`, not `std::string::str()` or `strcpy`.

I don't know if it's the only problem. `(width)*(height)` looks suspicious to me. Do you have one-byte pixels?

Comment: Yeah, i made those necessary corrections, which can be seen in the later part of the code.

As far as width width X height is concerned. No it's 4 byte, and because of that reason, there was distortion in my image. In any case the better way is to use (bytes_per_line*height)